# render two seaborn figure objects in same ipython cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have two matplotlib (seaborn) figure objects both made in different ipython cells.

```
#One Cell
fig_1_object = sns.factorplot(y='freq',x='d_fam',col='easy_donor',kind="bar",data=collection_d_fam)
fig_1 = fig_1_object.fig


#Two Cell
fig_2_object = sns.factorplot(y='freq',x='d_fam',col='easy_donor',kind="bar",data=collection_c_fam)
fig_2 = fig_2_object.fig
```

How can I "show" them one after another in the same cell. I have matplotlib inline turned on.

```
#third cell
fig_1
fig_2
>>Only shows fig_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to import the `display` function from the `IPython.display` module:

```
from IPython.display import display
import seaborn

%matplotlib inline

g1 = seaborn.factorplot(**options1)
g2 = seaborn.factorplot(**options2)

display(g1)
display(g2)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use plt.show() after each image:

```
sns.factorplot(y='freq',x='d_fam',col='easy_donor',kind="bar",data=collection_d_fam)
plt.show()

sns.factorplot(y='freq',x='d_fam',col='easy_donor',kind="bar",data=collection_c_fam)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(5,10))
plt.subplot(211)
# Figure 1
sns.factorplot(y='freq',x='d_fam',col='easy_donor',kind="bar",data=collection_d_fam)
plt.subplot(212)
# Figure 2
sns.factorplot(y='freq',x='d_fam',col='easy_donor',kind="bar",data=collection_c_fam)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//For displaying 2 or more fig in the same row or columns :-

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=2,figsize=(14,5))

//The above (ncols) take no of columns and (nrows) take no of rows and (figsize) to enlarge the image size.

sns.countplot(x=data['Rating'],palette="rocket",ax=axs[0][0])
sns.countplot(x=data['Rating'][0:50],palette="rocket",ax=axs[1][0])
sns.countplot(x=data['Rating'],palette="rocket",ax=axs[0][0])
sns.countplot(x=data['Rating'][0:50],palette="rocket",ax=axs[1][0])`
//Here in any plot u want to plot add **ax** and pass the position and you are ready !!!
```